Redis-backed rate limiter - implementing without transaction

I am looking to implement rate limiter per user id in a service that
runs across multiple pods.
I want to allow each user id to call an API
up to 10 times a minute.
I want to use Redis so rate limit can be over all pods and not per-pod
I have a Redis cluster

I read https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/incr/  and also multiple relevant StackOverflow threads but I still can't understand why, according to the documentation, the following naive approach won't work.
Pseudo-code:
minutesSinceEpoch = getMinutesSinceEpoch(currentTimestamp) 
key = rate:userId:minutesSinceEpoch 
callCounter = INCR(key)
EXPIRE(key, 60 seconds) 
if (callCounter > 10) {
     // return 429
}
else {
   // serve API
}

As far as I understand the only issue here would be if application restarts between  INCR and EXPIRE which might result in it not being expired and taking memory.
But the documentation claims that if I don't use MULTI/EXEC I will also have a race condition. I don't understand why. Redis is single threaded, INCR supposed to be atomic, the key is built based on current timestamp (so key that expires one minute later doesn't matter).
What am I missing? I want to avoid MULTI/EXEC if possible...
